# make write(...., position=append) faster in fortran

Tags: optimization, fortran

I know optimization questions are difficult to answer.
However, I will try to get an answer here:

I am trying to write some values to a file in a quite complex raytracing program (over 100+ subroutines)
This is happening inside a subroutine as seen below.

The program itself is very fast, but as soon as I reach the append it slows down dramatically. Is there some way I can make it quicker?

```
subroutine iterate_e_ring(i, k)
use otherfile, only: other_subroutine;
implicit none
integer(I2B), intent(in) :: i, k   ! element number and iteration counter
real(BW), dimension(3) :: converge  !Convergence check by Ole Müller
character*150 :: filename

call other_subroutine(x,y,z)
converge(1)= ...
converge(2)= ...
converge(3)= ...


   open(unit=120,file='converge.txt',action='write',position="append")
            write(120, *) real(converge(:))
   close(unit=120)

end subroutine iterate_e_ring;
```

Comment: How often/how many times do you call it? How much does a single call take? Do you need text files? Optimizations typically require **performance measurements** and only you can do them. Please supply them.

Comment: The obvious thing to do is 1. save the data in a buffer and write less often, 2. keep the file open, 3. use binary data.

Comment: But that is assuming you are calling it often to append some more data, but even that is not completely clear from you descriptions. More details are necessary.

Comment: I would try the suggestion to keep the file open as a first test :-)

Comment: @Vlad Keeping the file open is a good idea, i will try this, i guess for this i need to pass down k_max to know when to close it again right?
also about measurements, yes i should measure but i did not even know how to start, thats why i wanted some first ideas.
About how often it is called, that depends, around 100-1000 times

Comment: @busssard I have no idea what `k_max` might be, it does not appear in your code. We really need much more information to be able to answer in any useful way. You can use `system_clock()` for your measurements.